# query data from one table that matches with value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table created as

```
create table table1(id int,);
create table table2(id int, tb2_id int,...)
```

But when i try out

```
Select * from table2 where tb2_id=table1.id;
```

I have got an error that table1.id is an unknown column.

Could someone point out where the mistake I made is ?

Comment: what about `Select table2.* from table2, table1 where table2.tb2_id=table1.id;`

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) tables:

```
SELECT table2.* FROM table2 JOIN table1 ON (table2.tb2_id=table1.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from table2, table1 where tb2_id=table1.id;
```

Comment: or you can use `Select * from table2 t2, table1 t1 where t2.tb2_id=t1.id;`

Comment: it will throw an error... It should be `Select table2.* from table2, table1 where table2.tb2_id=table1.id;`

Comment: which query will throw the error? the one in the answer or the one in the comment and what is the error?

Comment: @Fahim: No it won't, there is no ambiguity about where `tb2_id` comes from so you don't need to prefix it; `id` must be prefix though because it appears in both tables. Always including the prefix is a good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

You need either a join or a subquery.

```
Select t2.*
from table2 t2
  Inner join table1 t1
     On t2.tbl2_id = t1.id
```

Or

```
Select t2.*
from table2 t2
where tbl2_id in ( select id from table1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table2
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Table1)
```